# Minimum Distance Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, distance, partitioning

I have been reading on here for a while, but this is the first time I have posted so I apologize if this isn't tagged correctly or anything. Anyway I am stuck on a problem which I explain below.

In the problem my job is to arrange n wifi routers to minimize the longest distance between any house and the nearest wifi router. I can assume that the houses are arranged in a one dimensional space. I am given the positions of the houses as a distance from an initial point and the positions are given in sorted order. Additionally I must solve this problem in O(m log L) where m is the number of houses and L is the maximum position that can be given.

I have tried to figure this out, but none of the algorithms that I come up with can solve it in the complexity required. Thanks for any hints on how I would go about solving this.

Comment: No dependence on `n`? Also, you can assume WLOG that all meters are located at a house or halfway between two houses.

Comment: I thought that it was strange that there was no dependence on 'n' also. I realized that the LOG had to give me some way to simplify the distances, but I can't figure out how to do it based upon the complexity of L.

Comment: Are the points you can place the routers at discrete or are they continuous?

Comment: @G Bach the bound on position implies it's discrete.

Comment: Then I'd assume the log L comes from a binary search for some form of center, meaning the point that has the least maximum distance to any of the m positions. You place one router there, then recurse on the lower/higher half; you'll need to think about a two-element center for each step of the recursion if you have an even number of routers left. At least that's what roughly comes to mind as an approach, no proof of optimality though. The m in the complexity probably comes from the fact that you need at most m routers, so even if you're given more that won't change the complexity.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that this is a real description of your job.

Comment: @G Bach, unfortunately, that's not optimal. I suspect there is a mistake in the problem.

Comment: @Antimony I was beginning to think there was a mistake in the way the problem is written too. I think that the binary search idea is along the right path but it seems like the problem may be incorrect since, as you pointed out, that solution is not optimal

Comment: Seems like k-means should do it, but I'm not aware of a proof on the time complexity of a discrete, one-dimensional version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint.

It is easy to write a `O(m)` function that takes an upper bound on distance, and tells you the minimum number of needed routers to make sure that no house is above that distance from a router.

Now search for the largest distance that uses no more than `n` routers.

Comment: The algorithm you are thinking about (if it is possible) gives the existence of a solution but not the actual coordinates for it.

Comment: The "easy" function I think he's referring to determines the "minimum" by greedily computing a router placement, which could be returned with the count.  What's hanging me up is whether or not the greedy algorithm could miss the true minimum.

Comment: @phs You can use induction to resolve that detail.  I'm deliberately leaving work to do in my description because I think that this is homework.

Comment: @btilly you are correct that this was for a homework problem. Thanks for answering it in a way that allowed me to still have to do some work.